# How to start 'View Contact' Activity on android?

Tags: android, contacts

I want to create a tab which contains a tab for viewing contact detail. Here is what i did:

```
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, ""+contactId));
    nativeInfo = tabHost.newTabSpec("native info").setIndicator("N Info").setContent(intent);
```

It throw security exception.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the exception and the permissions you have added in Manifest file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add that permission to your manifest file, so that the user gets notified your app will read contacts when the app is installed.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Take a look at this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms

Comment: im having problems viewing the native phone book from sony ericsson to my code using View